# How to prevent the "leave-notify-event" to treat the title bar as out of window?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm using pyGTK in Python 2.7 and I would to set `win.set_decorated(False)` when the mouse is outside of window and `win.set_decorated(True)` when the mouse is inside of window.

The code below works, but have a issue. When I put the mouse on title bar, the title bar got a collapse loop. Because the `leave-notify-event` treat the title bar as out of window. How can I fix it?

```
import gtk 

def mouse_enter(win, event): 
    win.set_decorated(True) 

def mouse_leave(win, event): 
    win.set_decorated(False) 

win = gtk.Window() 
win.connect('enter-notify-event', mouse_enter) 
win.connect('leave-notify-event', mouse_leave) 
win.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit) 
win.show_all() 
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're even getting into the `leave-notify-event`? You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721544/motion-notify-event-not-triggering).

Comment: @oldtechaa: It's hard to see how `win.set_decorated(False)` could be called if `leave-notify-event` isn't generated...

Comment: @SiHa, I'm asking for some clarification. If the OP is getting the desired behavior, what exactly is the problem? If they're not, which I don't see how they could be without a call to `add_events()` as in my link, then have they tried that solution?