# motion-notify-event not triggering

Tags: python, gtk

Basically what i need to achieve with this is to bypass the bug which doesn't identify the mouse over the top bar as being inside the window. As you can see with the code below, if you put the mouse on top bar the window turns half-transparent as if the mouse aren't there (`mouse_enter()` doesn't get called).

Well, so i thought the only way to do this is to get mouse coordenates/position and work from there in the `mouse_move()` function, the problem now is that `motion-notify-event` doesn't get fired.

```
import gtk

def mouse_move(window, event):
    print(win.get_pointer())
    win.set_opacity(1)

def mouse_enter(window, event):
    win.set_opacity(1)

def mouse_leave(window, event):
    win.set_opacity(0.5)

win = gtk.Window()
win.set_opacity(0.5)
win.set_size_request(600, 400)

win.connect('enter-notify-event', mouse_enter)
win.connect('leave-notify-event', mouse_leave)
win.connect('motion-notify-event', mouse_move)
win.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to call `win.add_events()` with the Python equivalent of `GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK`.

Comment: Sintaticly how would i do that? i did `win.add_events(POINTER_MOTION_MASK)`, and throws `NameError: name 'GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK' is not defined`

Comment: I wouldn't know; you would need to look up a PyGTK reference. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks though @andlabs

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html has information about this

Comment: I think it's `gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK`

Comment: [Here's](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-EventHandling.html) the full list.